# Python script runs while loop twice when it shouldn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, user-input

I am out of ideas to try and fix this weird issue. I hope someone here will catch what I missed.
The while loop in this script runs in a weird way, can you help me figure out why?
First it skips all the contents of the loop after the user input and loops over once, then it executes the results of the inputs of both loops. No error message is shown. This is what the shell I run the scripts from says after I'm done:

```
$ What type of task are we looking at, here? XX
$ What type of task are we looking at, here? XX
$ Generating a new checklist file on your desktop...
$ Generating a new checklist file on your desktop...
```

Here is the code (I am a beginner so please have mercy, but feedback is welcome):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


current_task = "" #Defining this here so that it can be imported into checklist_items.py

def main():

    import os, datetime, HTML_file_wrapper
    from checklist_items import get_checklist_items
    global current_task


    new_checklist = []
    def checklist_maker(task: dict):
        bullet = 0  # keeps track of the number of previous steps for the list to be numbered
        for step in task:
            if task[step] is True:
                bullet += 1
                new_checklist.append(f"\t{bullet}– {step}")

    while True:
        current_task = str(input("What type of task are we looking at, here? "))

        if current_task.lower() == "help":
            pass
            # TODO: Include a list of stuff that can be done

        elif "test" in current_task.lower():
            checklist_maker(get_checklist_items().test)
            break

        elif "yy" in current_task:
            checklist_maker(get_checklist_items().YY)
            break

        elif "xx" in current_task.lower():
            checklist_maker(get_checklist_items().XX)
            break

        else:
            print("I don't understand  Please try to say it a different way.")


    print("Generating a new checklist file on your desktop...")
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop'), f"checklist_{current_date.strftime('%d%m%Y')}_{current_date.strftime('%H%M')}.html"), "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(HTML_file_wrapper.top)
        for string in new_checklist:
            f.write(string + "<br>\n")
        f.write(HTML_file_wrapper.bottom)


main()
```

Comment: Don't define a function inside another function (unless you know what you're doing).

Comment: `elif "XX" in current_task.lower():`: how can "XX" occur in a lowercase string?! (hint: it can't)

Comment: You're right, it's a placeholder for the purposes of Stack Overflow replacing the actual value, and I didn't think of this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Are you importing this into another script AND calling the main() function of this script from that one?

Comment: Yes! The other file essentially contains a few dicts and some fluff around them to avoid circular import errors.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/6394617)

Comment: @Joe: Thank you. I am aware of this concept, but the script I am showing here is actually itself going to be called upon by another script. It's the main file in a local module, and, if I understand correctly, ```if __name__ = __main__``` etc. specifically blocks the script from running if it is imported.

Comment: it would stop the main function from running on import, but is there any reason why, wherever you import it as foo, you can't just immediately call foo.main(), if that's what you want?

Comment: I didn't know that was an option. I'll definitely put the whole main function call then. Thanks. I don't think that's the cause if the issue because it was working until I refactored the whole module to avoid circular import errors. If the weird thing I have going on there with the while loop doesn't have a simple solution, I think I'll merge all files in the module into one, with both dependencies as classes, and that'll be that. The stakes are too low to spend years on this.